# Having a datetime picker in a partial view inside a JQuery bootstrap model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to have a bootstrap model with and date picker in it.  Which I have copied everything from this example and got working  fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/93eTU/

The problem is, my dialog contents are partial views and set up with JQuery.  It seem to never show the date picker.   I have copied the relevant sections of my code.

So on the screen there is  be a button like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEdit"
        data-itemId=@item.ItemId
        data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#myModal">
        Edit
</button>
```

Which has a JQuery click event

```
$(document).on("click", "# btnEdit", function (e) {
   $.ajax({ url: "/Item/Edit",
            datatype: "text",
            data: { itemId: $(this).attr('data-ItemId) },
            type: "GET",
          }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
          $(".modal-content").html(partialViewResult);
    });
});
```

});
That then goes to the MVC controller called ItemController and calls Edit which gets the partial view
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid itemId)
    {
       return PartialView("_Edit", GetByItemID(itemId) );
    }

The Edit partial view looks like this, and this is what is not displaying the input with the id datepicker

```
@model Project.Models.Item
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Item</h4>
     </div>
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"></p>
 </div>
}

@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

There is JS getting called that give everything with class datepicker a datepicker.  It works when the text box is anywhere else, expect when it on a dialog

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

I also have the CSS doing this

```
.clsDatePicker {  z-index: 100000; }
```

Comment: where's your model... secondly it seems you are initializing model before it gets return on view ... Take a close look and make sure your model gets load before you initialize....

Comment: User are you asking about the mvc model, Its just got 3 properties, a guid id field, a string name field and a date time field.  Its mapping got removed from partial view, when I was getting angry at not working code.

Comment: I'll try to answer ur qustion tomorrow with working code :)

Comment: Your dynamically adding the contents of the modal, so you need to attach the plugin to the element after you have added it to the DOM (i.e. after `$(".modal-content").html(partialViewResult);`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is your JS for datetimePicker plugin is getting loaded before you are adding modal content form your prartial view, in this case when DOM is already ready plugin will not find the element dynamically added from view.

try initializing your datetimepicker after you add content from your dynamic view

```
$(document).on("click", "# btnEdit", function (e) {
   $.ajax({ url: "/Item/Edit",
            datatype: "text",
            data: { itemId: $(this).attr('data-ItemId) },
            type: "GET",
          }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
          $(".modal-content").html(partialViewResult);
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
});
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: cheers, it worked like a charm.  I could even get rid of the Z index css which is always a code smell.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks so much. It saved my day. :)

Comment: You are beautiful. Was searching everywhere and this works for me.